# Easy calculus question

Tags: calculus

Let $D = \{ (x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq 1, \; \; x^2 \leq y \leq x, \; \; 0 \leq z \leq x \} $

and suppose $f(x,y,z) = x + y $. Want: $\int_D f $

IS this the correct integral?

$$ \int_{0}^1 \int_{x}^{x^2} \int_{0}^x (x + y) dzdydx $$

By the way, since $f$ is continuous on $D$, then integral above makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch the limits on the middle integral, since $x^2$ is smaller than $x$ within your domain. It'll have the effect of switching the sign on the final product. Other than that, it's good.